# Proposal to add brief description of each site to Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I am a new user in Stack Exchange. The names of some Stack Exchange sites are confusing.

I read in one post that questions related to Windows should be asked in Super User. But the name Super User shouted "Linux" to me. To avoid confusion, can the community add a brief two-line explanation on what the site is about which can be viewed from site-specific menu whenever needed? I don't know if this system exists in the desktop version, but I have not found it in Android.

I know there is a question which specifically deals with what site is for what, but I am proposing taking this answer to the readers, so that they don't make a couple of mistakes before thinking to or being referred to that question.

I believe it will help prevent a lot of migration traffic.

Comment: If you go to "All Sites" in the app, every site has a one-line description which matches what is displayed at http://stackexchange.com/sites (less the "Q&A for " text). How is your proposal different?

Comment: Hi, I saw the description. I think they are there to grab the attention and pull you to that site. It does not tell anything about what not to post and can be misguiding. For example, there is a discussion in su which strictly forbids posting anything mobile related, even if it has nothing to do with mobile OS and has everything to do with mobile hardware. There was an argument about where to post a question about mobile hardware. So what I am suggesting is to tell the user to avoid posing about so and so in this site. Also make it clear by telling this is what you can ask.

Comment: _"But the name Super User shouted 'Linux' to me._" That's your failing, not SE's. If you want to find out what a site's about, read one of the twenty bloody _trillion_ FAQ and Help pages that someone spent years writing for precisely that purpose for precisely people like you. **Why does nobody read documentation any more?** Frak me. _Big_ downvote from me.

Comment: That is the norm and not my failing. If you keep a name associated with Linux, the general expectation is that you mean “Linux”. If this sounds weird to you then I can't help it. Generation gap I guess. Plus for a new user it takes time to know how the site works, especially when useful things like help center are not readily available and no question turns up when searching using search bar, but every question asked turns out to be duplicate as pointed out by others and people have no civility to be polite.

Comment: I am writing about the android app. Do you even use it? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @CRags: Yes, I do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I started using SE one week ago using the android app, where a lot of useful things like related questions, help center, etc... are not visible at all. So I think it's ok for me to stumble through the way in the process of learning

Comment: @CRags: Yes, I agree. I was responding only to the statement that I directly quoted.

Comment: But don't you think that's true? What will you think first when you hear such a name? I did not mean to say that I posted questions about linux in that community. I just meant that the names are misleading and the two line descriptions don't provide much info. For someone who uses computer, the first time (s)he logs into the site, it asks if (s)he would take a tour to know what this site is about. Nothing like that is seen in the android app. That's why I asked for that feature

Comment: I should also say that I am just learning. This is perhaps the day 10 or 9 since I started using SE. So please bear with me.